# Tauri and Mysql

Tags: mysql, desktop-application, tauri

I'm trying to build a simple application using Tauri.

I want to use mysql(or postgress...) for the backend.

But I do not find anything on how I can implement mysql with rust using Diesel or sqlx etc.

I tried their pluging https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri-plugin-sql but got multiple errors when trying to run/build the app.

TLDR : Do you know how I can implement a database to my Tauri App (not sqlite) ?

Comment: Have you tried this https://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started? Can you share your build rrors?